# Check if a file is opened by another application in C?

Tags: c, linux, file, file-io

I am trying to write a program which will encrypt a file and save the result to another file. As part of the assignment, we are not allowed to use standard C library functions like `fopen()`, `fgets()`, `fscanf()`, etc to write to the file. Instead, we can only use Unix system calls like `open()`, `read()`, `write()`, and `close()`. However, I would like to make sure that my output file has not been opened by another application before writing to it. is there any facility to do this in C?

Comment: Can't be done in all operating systems. Unix provides a way to indicate that you want exclusive access to a file, but doesn't require that programs honor this request.

Comment: I see, how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a pseudo-random file name and open the file with (O_CREATE | O_EXCL) as options.  If the file already exists, the open will fail with EEXIST and you can try again with a new name.

Note that this doesn't *guarantee* anything, just reduces the possibility.  A true guarantee will require filesystem and OS specific methods.

Comment: cool, I see. I'll be running `CentOS 5.8` and `FreeBSD 8.2` for this assignment

Comment: Er, actually, `O_CREATE | O_EXCL` does guarantee that the file is newly created. That's the whole point of `O_EXCL`! (But it doesn't guarantee that nobody else can open it *later*.)

Comment: Right.  This only guarantees that you don't have an initial collision.  Very much Security Through Obscurity.